# Store a Facebook Access token in Mysql to post to wall later

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

I am using the following code to store my facebook app users details in mysql to allow them to see exclusive content on my website.

My question is simple, How can I store the access token of the user in my Mysql table to use it later to post to wall later

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST["connect"]) && $_POST["connect"]==1)
 {      
include_once("config.php"); //Include configuration file.

//Call Facebook API
if (!class_exists('FacebookApiException')) {
require_once('inc/facebook.php' );
}
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $appId,
    'secret' => $appSecret,
));

$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
if ($fbuser) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $me = $facebook->api('/me'); //user
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        //echo error_log($e);
        $fbuser = null;
    }
}





// redirect user to facebook login page if empty data or fresh login requires
if (!$fbuser){
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$return_url, false));
    header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
}

//user details
$fullname = $me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name'];
$email = $me['email'];
$username = $me['username'];
$gender = $me['gender'];
$locale = $me['locale'];
$token = $me['token'];

/* connect to mysql */
$connecDB = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_username, $db_password)or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");   
mysql_select_db($db_name,$connecDB);

//Check user id in our database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM usertable WHERE fbid=$uid");   
$UserCount = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

if($UserCount[0])
{   
    //User exist, Show welcome back message
echo 'Ajax Response :<br /><strong>Welcome back '. $me['first_name'] . ' '. $me['last_name'].'!</strong> AT : '.$token.' ( Facebook ID : '.$uid.') [<a href="'.$return_url.'?logout=1">Log Ouuuuuuuuuuuuuut</a>]';
echo '<iframe style="width:1309px; height:526px" src="post2.php"></iframe>';

    //User is now connected, log him in
    login_user(true,$me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name']);
}
else
{
    //User is new, Show connected message and store info in our Database
    // Insert user into Database.
    @mysql_query("INSERT INTO usertable (fbid, fullname, email, username, gender, token, locale) VALUES ($uid, '$fullname','$email','$username','$gender','$token','$locale')");

    //User is now connected, log him in
    login_user(true,$me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name']);
}

mysql_close($connecDB);
   }

  function login_user($loggedin,$user_name)
  {
/*
function stores some session variables to imitate user login. 
We will use these session variables to keep user logged in, until s/he clicks log-out link.
If you are using some authentication library, login user with it instead.
*/
$_SESSION['logged_in']=$loggedin;
$_SESSION['user_name']=$user_name;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: if you want to publish on the user's wall when he is offline you just need the `publish_stream` permission, you **don't** even need a user access token...use the PHP-SDK directly and it'll add the app access token automatically and that would work. P.S.: your code needs some attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand. You are already saving the token.

What you need to, is to verify in the authenticated-only page if the user is logged in, if so, you will return the token for his $_SESSION['user_id'] (for ex.), and create the interactions within Facebook API with that token, using for example:

```
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
$facebook->setAccessToken($token);
```

I hope It did help you.

Comment: I am looking for the off-line token. I want to post a message on a user's wall even if he is not connected to FB.

Comment: You can do that, you need to ask the publish_stream permission too to get it allowed in the access token. I would recommend you to "ask" for the extended access token before saving it (the one that expires in 60 days), using:

    $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
    $fb_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

Don't forget that tokens expire! You always need to have an exception in case that the token is not valid anymore and user needs to refresh it.

Comment: in the config.php file I have asked for the 'publish_stream, offline_access' permissions. My app can publish a message on the user's wall but I want to be able to post a message to all my application users on the go. just like in this application if I want to update users wall http://yougapi.com/products/facebook_viral/admin/

Comment: I would, but the concept of StackOverflow is letting the answers here to help other people in future. From what I see, you could create a form, where you would write a message, and when clicking the submit button, it will run a foreach of all the results that have the fb_token filled, and will run a PHP post to wall to everyone. Isn't that that you are looking for?

Comment: cactually u can try my raw app here http://nizar.kodingen.com/connect/index.php If you want I can past the whole code for u because I tried many things but it seems that all of them were not successfull

Comment: What is the returned error after you try to post on behalf of the user? So the problem is saving the user token, or posting on behalf of him?

Comment: the problem is saving the user token. When I try saving it. Nothig is posted here

Comment: Before saving make a die("Token: ".$token); to check what is it getting.

Comment: Right after $token = $me['token'];

You need to know if you are really getting the token in that variable, if not, you would never have anything in database.

Comment: I have changed my script. Now it gives me the following error Here is my new code http://pastebin.com/zQsyMTyj the error is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CATCH in httpdocs/connect/process_facebook.php on line 81 "

Comment: I would bet you are getting that unexpected T_CATCH because you didn't started a "try" for that catch.